# What are episodic and non-episodic domains in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, terminology, temporal-difference-methods, environment

I was reading about the temporal difference (TD) learning and I read that:

> TD handles continuing, non-episodic domains

Assuming that continuing means non-terminating, what does non-episodic or episodic domain mean?

Comment: Here's another relevant post [https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/271356/82135](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/271356/82135).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assuming that continuing means non terminating, what does non-episodic or episodic domain mean ?

Non-episodic means the same as continuing. The quote you found is not listing two separate domains, the word "continuing" is slightly redundant. I expect the author put it in there to emphasise the meaning, or to cover two common ways of describing such environments.

Episodic domain problems are ones that terminate, or otherwise naturally split into groups of time steps that can be considered separately.